# McNemar's test for $3 \times 2$ data

Tags: r, repeated-measures, mcnemar-test

I adopt a within-group experiment, such that the same participant uses 3 devices to perform a task, which has a result "pass" or fail.
My data looks like this:

```
        Pass  Fail
deviceA   21    13
deviceB   15    20
deviceC   9     25
```

My questions are:

1. Is McNemar's test appropriate for this data?
2. In R, when I run `mcnemar.test(data)`, I got the following error:

   ```
   "'x' must be square with at least two rows and columns"
   ```

How can I run this $3 \times 2$ data for R's `mcnemar.test`?

Comment: I have the same general question. According to Wikipedia, [McNemar's test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McNemar's_test) should be applied to 2*2 test. Not an expert here, but you might be able to test in pairs: deviceA vs deviceB, deviceB vs deviceC, deviceA vs deviceC. I am not sure if this would be equivalent though but maybe somebody reading this could help

Comment: McNemar test is only for square frequency tables with rows/columns defined by the two variables with the same categories. Classic McNemar is for 2x2 table; its extension McNemar-Bowker is for kxk table. Your table is not appropriate for McNemar. What is your hypothesis, what do you want to test?

Comment: @ttnphns my null hypothesis is that the device type doesn't affect participants' task performance (pass or fail). Since McNemar and its extension both requires the data matrix to be square, then I assume McNemar is not appropriate for my data? In that case, should I test each pair of device, for example, deviceA and deviceB, using McNemar? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you have a 3-level factor "device", which is a repeated-measures factor. The response data are binary: 1 (pass) and 0 (fail).

```
respondent  deviceA  deviceB  deviceC
1              0        1        0
2              1        1        0
3              1        1        0
4              0        0        1
...
```

You want to test if the factor affects the result, i.e. if the 3 devices differ significantly. Null hypothesis: no differences between the 3 devices in the population; alternative hypothesis: there is some difference, at least between some 2 of the 3 devices.

Use **Friedman's test** (= Friedman's nonparametric "analysis-of-variance"). When the data values are all binary, this test is then also known as **Cochran's Q test**.

Please note that the frequency table corresponding to your analysis is size `2x2x2`, not `2x2` as McNemar's test implies (or `kxk`, for McNemar-Bowker), nor `3x2` as you thought. Cochran's Q test is the extension of McNemar's test from 2-way table to multi-way table.